# cannot load firefox profile with selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, centos, pip

I have 2 machines Centos 6.7, with exactly the same version of pip, python, firefox and selenium. 
Python 2.6.6,
pip 7.1.0,
selenium==2.52.0,
Mozilla Firefox 38.6.1,
PyVirtualDisplay==0.2,

my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver


display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
print browser.page_source

browser.close()
display.stop()
```

**in one machine it works perfectly**, in the other machine it gives me this error

```
        browser = webdriver.Firefox (firefox_binary = webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary (log_file = open ('/tmp/selenium.log', 'a')))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 106, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpDZ6INh If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

do you have any idea about this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that 127.0.0.1 blocked in the machine firewall !!!! that's strange !! and that was the problem